# Odd behaviour when saving instances in Ruby DataMapper

Tags: ruby, datamapper

having just started to look at DataMapper for Ruby ORM I've run into an issue that confuses me to no end.

The default behaviour when saving instances in DataMapper (through **DataMapper::Resource.save**) is, as far as I understand, to silently fail, return false from the save method and collect any errors in the errors collection. So far so good, this works as expected. The issue I see is with natural primary keys, where setting duplicate ones will throw an exception instead of silently returning **false** from the save method, blatantly disregarding the current setting of **raise_on_save_failure**. Consider the following snippet;

```
 require 'data_mapper'

class Thing
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :name , String, :key=>  true
  property :description, String, length: 2..5
end

DataMapper.setup :default, "sqlite:memory"
DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_migrate!

#Create a thing and have it properly silently fail saving
t1=Thing.new(:name=>"n1",:description=>"verylongdescription" )

t1.save #ok
puts("t1 is saved:"+t1.saved?.to_s)
t1.errors.each do |e|
  puts e
end

#Create two things with the same key, and fail miserably in silently failing the second     save...
t1=Thing.new(:name=>"n1",:description=>"ok" )
t2=Thing.new(:name=>"n1",:description=>"ok" )

t1.save #ok
t2.save #not ok, raises Exception event though it shouldn't?

puts("t2 is saved:"+t1.saved?.to_s)
t2.errors.each do |e|
  puts e
end
```

The first save, on an instance failing a validation rule for the :description property behaves as expected. The third save, of an instance with duplicate keys, however does not, since it raises an execption instead of nicely just returning false.

Why is this? It is obviously possible to work around, but it doesn't feel very clear. Is the case that the silent behaviour will only apply to validation errors in the DataMapper layer, and any hard errors from the underlying datastore will be propagated as exceptions to the caller?

Thanks!

Comment: Validations catch end user errors, a duplicate key getting down to the database is a programmer error. If you divide by zero or don't handle a `nil` properly during the `save` sequence you'll get an exception for the same reason.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense as a distinction, and I now understand the purpose of validations and silent/nonsilent behaviour a bit more in DataMapper.  I'm then guessing that in the example above, if you added a unique validation;

Comment: Unfortunately a uniqueness validation isn't enough as it is subject to race conditions so you need a unique constraint in the database as well, but then you get an exception when the race condition happens.

Answer (score 2):

As another user pointed out in a comment, this happens because setting `raise_on_save_failure` to `false` doesn't mean that no exceptions will occur. It will always return `false` (with no exceptions) when validation errors occur.

Database errors will blow up, as you noticed, in the form of an exception. Such errors could happen due to a large number of factors (the connection failed, no disk space), including mundane ones like a duplicate key. DataMapper can't know whether the object you're trying to save possesses a duplicate key, so it just validates it and sends to the database, where the error actually occurs.